# Given an algebra structure $(X,*)$ s.t. $(x*y)*y = y*(y*x) = x$ , prove$x*y=y*x$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, magma

Suppose $(X,*)$ is arbitrary algebraic structure such that $\forall x,y\in X$, we have $(x*y)*y = y*(y*x) = x$, prove that $x*y=y*x$.

This question seems pretty simple but I tried and I failed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the condition, we have
$$
\begin{cases}
\underline{(x*(x*y))*(x*y)} = (x*y)*((x*y)*x)=\underline{x}  &(1) \\
(y*x)*x = \underline{x*(x*y)=y} &(2) \\
((x*y)*y)*y = \underline{y*(y*(x*y)) = x*y}  &(3) 
\end{cases}
$$
for all $x,y \in X.$

Therefore
$$
\begin{align*}
y*x &= y*((x*(x*y))*(x*y)) & \textrm{by (1)} \\
  &= y*(y*(x*y))  & \textrm{by (2)}\\
&= x*y & \textrm{by (3)}\\
\end{align*}
$$
Q.E.D.